# Bind views automatically by name

Tags: android, findviewbyid, butterknife

Writing boilerplate code always bothers me. One of these things in Android is binding views:

```
TextView email;
TextView password;
//...

private bindViews() {
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
    //...
}
```

Which I think could be made better.

Recently I found out about [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library and I loved it. It makes code less:

```
@BindView(R.id.email) TextView email;
@BindView(R.id.password) TextView password;
//...

ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

But the thing is that we usually name our views match their ids. For example both xml id and java field name is `password`. (And also convert snake-casing to camel-casing). So I was thinking that theoretically the id part could also be removed and the code be shortened to something like this:

```
@BindView TextView email;
@BindView TextView password;
//...

bind(this);
```

Is there such solution? If there isn't, would it be useful and viable? Because I'd like to create it, if there's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't anything like that. But ButterKnife is actively worked on and has a pretty big following. I personally wouldn't switch away from that just to make my code slightly less verbose.

It'd still be a pretty cool exercise to do I think. Could fork ButterKnife and try to get that feature merged in. It'd be a pretty big achievement to contribute to one of Jake Wharton's libraries.

For what this is worth, you might like [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare). It's a JSON Parser that does basically the same thing you're describing with Annotations. It's also *very* fast. Here's an example of using it:

```
@JsonObject
public class User{
    // Will infer JSON key based off variable's name
    @JsonField
    public String name;

    // Can specify a key's name too if you want like this 
    @JsonField(name="date_of_birth")
    public long dateOfBirth;

    // LoganSquare requires a default constructor like this
    public User(){}
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, good to know. The Json parser is cool too, thanks for sharing.